# How can I solve this function problem?

Tags: functions

for the number $3$ if I put $-x$ in the place of $x$ then I will get $2$ equations by which I can get $f(x)$. But what about the others? I've no idea how to solve these.

$$(1)\quad f(\frac{1+x}{1-x})+f(\frac{1-x}{1+x})=2;\ f(x)=?$$
$$(2)\quad f(2^x)+f(2^{-x})=1;\ f(x)=?$$
$$(3)\quad f(x)+xf(-x)=x;\ f(x)=?$$
$$(4)\quad f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y);\ f(1)=?$$

Comment: For $(4)$, any $f(x) = kx$ will satisfy that, so there is no single answer.

Comment: For (2) you could basically pick anything you like for $x>1$ as long as $f(x^{-1})=1-f(x)$, but $$\frac{1}{2}+c\ln(x)$$ would work, with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In (1) apply $x\mapsto\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$

Comment: There are some conditions required (eg continuity of $f$) to make this at all interesting.